# RMAN 11g/12c Client compatibility

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, rman, oracle-12c

I'm having a Recovery catalog database 12c version. While I'm trying to register the target database (11g) with the catalog I get the following error:

`Recovery Manager: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Fri Aug 14 13:03:44 2015`

`Copyright 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.`

`RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00554: initialization of internal recovery manager package failed
RMAN-06429: TARGET database is not compatible with this version of RMAN
RMAN-06618: RMAN client and database release mismatch; indicated database release is 11.2.0.4`

I have checked the compatibility matrix, it says the RMAN client and the target database has to be the same version. But I'm using Catalog as 12c database therefore the client is 12 as well. Should I use RMAN 11g client to connect to the target? If yes, How should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You must use the RMAN executable that is in the classpath that is used to run (or how would you say that) your database. That is the one from 11g. Just do `. oraenv <database>` (note space between . and oraenv) to set the correct path and then execute `rman`.

Comment: How to set the 11g path? Im registering the target from my 12c catalog db as  rman target sys/****@TESTDB CATALOG rman/*****@catalogdb. Now where to set the that path? Here,  that TESTDB is the 11g db.

Comment: Do not know. I always launch my rman on the server that hosts the database. I guess that you will need to install 11g on the server on which you run your 12c catalog.

Answer (score 2):

As per compatibility matrix, the target and the RMAN client version has to be the same. The workaround is connect to the catalog database from the target database ( whose version is lower than that of the RMAN client) and register the database in the catalog.

Thanks!